# How to add a button inside a new window object and call the function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to learn. I have a button which opens up a new window which then pops up an alert message after 10 seconds using the setTimeout method. But I would like to have a button that stops it before the message appears using the clearTimeout method. I managed to create a button but when I click the button nothing happens so i don't know why this doesn't work and would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
function newWindow4(){
    var window4 = window.open('', '_blank', 'location=no');
    window4.document.write('In 10 seconds there will be a message!');
    var x = setTimeout(function(){
        window4.alert('Here is the message');
    }, 10000);

    window4.document.write('<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>');

    function stop(){
        clearTimeout(x);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things - some of them would be clear in the console (F12 in windows)

1. `window4.document.close()` after the last write
2. `opener.stopMe()` after renaming the function since window.stop is a reserved name - also it needs to be tested that it exists at the time of the click
3. add type="button" to the button since some browsers will think it is a submit button
4. move the window4, x and stopMe outside the function otherwise it will not be visible to the timeout (scope)

Like this:

```
var x, window4;
function stopMe(){
    clearTimeout(x);
}   

function newWindow4(){
    window4 = window.open('', '_blank', 'location=no');
    window4.document.write('In 10 seconds there will be a message!');
    x = setTimeout(function(){
        window4.alert('Here is the message');
    }, 10000);

    window4.document.write('<button type="button" onclick="if (opener && opener.stopMe) opener.stopMe()">Stop</button>');
    window4.document.close();
}
```

I cannot off the top of my head remember if the browser also needs to be told it is opener.x that needs to be cleared

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem! I have not been using the console but will use it from now on. I didn't know that window.stop was a reserved name. What does opener refer to, that's also a reserved name?

Comment: opener is the window that opened the popup. It has the stopMe function and the x you need to clear. if you run stopMe from the popup it has to live in the popup - for example by document.writing a script or a pointer to an external script tag. Be advised that there are very few reasons to have a popup when you can hide and show a dialog in the page by coding a simple div in the page. Popups are generally blocked by default. See https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for great examples

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on create it dynamically... if you can inject a tag button, you can also inject a script tag

```
var window4 = window.open('', '_blank', 'location=no');
window4.document.write('In 10 seconds there will be a message!');

window4.document.write(
   '<script>                                '+
   'var x = setTimeout(function() {         '+
   '  alert("Here is the message");         '+
   '}, 10000);                              '+
   'function stopIt() {                     '+
   '   clearTimeout(x);                     '+
   '}                                       '+
   '<\/script>                              '+
   '<button onclick="stopIt()">Stop</button>'
);
window4.document.close();
```

Comment: but make SURE you escape the end script: <\/script> and CLOSE the document and rename the stop.